# Какой лучший продукт для создания Базы данных в Linux

Tags: база-данных, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, наиболее удобное средство для создания Базы Данных в Linux.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы на мой вопрос. Понимаю, что вопрос задан был не вполне корректно, тем не менее Ваши ответы дают новые или более точные направления действий. Ситуация такая.Есть БД клиентов созданная в Access на скорую руку лет 10 назад. Недавно начал свое знакомство с Linux и решил эту БД перенести на эту ОС. Или создать новую БД с учетом новых требований. Меня заинтересовала возможность связки MSSQL+Access, но с другой стороны хочется автономности от продуктов Microsoft. Как сказал мой знакомый: "Чем больше я узнаю Linux, тем меньше мне нравится Microsoft"

Answer (score 2):

Дополню первые два ответа...
Подключаемым интерфейсом для разработки приложений/работы с базой может служить OpenOffice или LibreOffice. Это будет похоже на связку MSSQL+Access.
Если же требуется аналог Access, то в указанных офисных пакетах это возможно (создание файла базы данных и "рисование" интерфейса к ней) - но это для несерьезных проектов, а`ля "каталог моих книг" - для этого в указанных офисных пакетах должен быть установлен пакет Base.
Однако, ИМХО, лучше использовать "нормальные" серверы баз данных - MySQL, Postgree и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос интересный, но, к сожалению, совершенно неконкретный. Все базы данных имеют свои слабые и сильные стороны. На что надо обратить внимание

- цена (платные-бесплатные)
- технология (SQL-NoSQL)
- размещение (диск-память)
- открытость (открытый код - закрытый код)
- популярность
- зрелость
- и т.д. и т.п.

Вообще, если вопрос ставится таким образом, то стоит ознакомится с [основами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), а выбрать достаточно то, что использует большинство для типовых проектов - это MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

*sql в зависимости от задачи

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор Руна: http://runabase.ru/download.html

Из Access через Excel можно экспортировать все данные в файл с расширением .csv, а он уже понимается в конструкторе Руна и можно импортировать в любой объект.

Comment: не реклама ли это?